# Center align Logo and align UL horizontally around it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to capture a layout that I have seen a few different places.  The layout has a fixed header with an image centered, and then a horizontal UL that is split around the logo.  Attached is the image that I feel represents this.

I need a suggestion to achieve splitting the UL around logo. Right now the UL is always under and not split.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgac8/1/

Here is some markup that I have been attempting:
HTML

```
<header>
<h1 id="logo"><a href="index"></a></h1>
<nav>
<a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="services">services</a></li>
<li><a href="location">location</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
text-align:center;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background:#FF7D0D;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
z-index:100;
}

#logo {
display: inline-block;
padding:5px 0 0 0;
width: 80px;
height: 150px;
background: url(../img/PP_Logo_Vert_White.png) center no-repeat;
}

nav {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size:16px;
font-weight: 100;
clear:left;
}

nav ul {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
list-style: none;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: What does "align ul horizontally around it" mean? A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: I added a fiddle, I cannot upload pictures because of my status.  Image centered with a split UL on left and right of image.  LINK - LINK LOGO LINK - LINK

Comment: Your fiddle does not describe the desired state, so this is a little hard to figure out.

Comment: So via the set up on fiddle, the UL  is below the image.  How does one achieve making it inline with the logo?  In other words, move the UL (links) up about 100px or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to do a bit of tweaking but I believe it is what you want.

HTML

```
<header>
<h1 id="logo"><a href="index"></a></h1>
<nav id="left">
<a href="#" ></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="services">services</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

    <nav id="right">
<a href="#" ></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="services">services</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
text-align:center;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background:#FF7D0D;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
z-index:100;
}

#logo {
display: inline-block;
padding:5px 0 0 0;
width: 80px;
height: 150px;
background: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/2141/web_design_creatives/128/small_smile.png) center no-repeat;
}

#left{position:absolute; left:10%; top:5px; list-style:none}

#right{position:absolute; right:10%; top:5px; list-style:none}

li{list-style:none}
```

Comment: Thanks Kale.  I am looking at this now in fiddle.

Comment: You might need to change the percentages a bit or if you want to use another unit that's fine. If it works make sure to select the post as answered.

Comment: Yeah I changed the top and the left right to get the desired result. However, the UL is now split into two UL's which changed how the effect of my css media queries were working.  How do I mark the post as answered?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. Make sure you are logged in

Comment: Okay thanks Kale.  Your answer was it for the most part, specifically the positioning.  What I ended up doing so that the logo and ul is always centered is also set the width to 100%.  I actually ended up leaving the UL as one list and not splitting it into two.  I then increased the padding to adjust for the logo. Boom! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this.  Depending on how dynamic your site will be.  If you are creating it with static html and css I would simply create a container, put three divs inside the container splitting it up how you want.  In the first and third div create two separate menus.  In the center put the logo.  Something like the code below.  At a certain width you can create some css media queries to bring it down and make it one navigation.

The very basic idea:

Example of html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-nav">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="right-nav">
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

.right-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin Zaki.  The site isn't dynamic other than on a few css media queries depending on size, I transition the NAV/UL to a side bar.  In what I had going it was all one UList rather than split into two.  Hmmm… I might need to rethink that part too now.